# Prove $\forall x(A \vee B(x)) \therefore A \vee \forall xB(x)$.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

Working on P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 297, exercise C. 3):

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{\forall x(A \vee B(x))}{
  \fitch{\neg(A \vee \forall xB(x))}{
 \fitch{\neg A}{
     A \vee B(c) \qquad (\forall E, 1)\\
     \fitch{A}{
       \bot \qquad (\neg E, 3, 5)\\
       B(c) \qquad (X, 6)\\
     }\\
     \fitch{B(c)}{
       B(c) \qquad (R, 8)
     }\\
     B(c) \qquad (\vee E, 5-7,8-9)\\
     \forall xB(x) \qquad (\forall I, 10)\\
     A \vee \forall xB(x) \qquad (\vee I,11)\\
     \bot \qquad (\vee I,1, 11)\\
   }\\
   A \qquad (IP, 3-12)\\
   A \vee \forall xB(x) \qquad (\vee I,13)\\
   \bot \qquad (\neg E, 1,14)\\
 }\\
 A \vee \forall xB(x) \qquad (IP, 1-15)\\
}
$

Is this the right approach to this proof ?

Comment: I derive $A \vee B(c)$ by $\mathbf{\forall E }$ line 1 .

Comment: Okay, I see what you're doing, but it would be good to use such abbreviations in your steps of the proof., and to identify the step(s) involved in your justification, e.g., (1, $\forall E$.)

Comment: What do you mean by abbreviations ?

Comment: I provided you with an example.  E.g., $A\lor B(c) \tag{1, $\forall E$}$ Or, $$A\lor (B(c)) \qquad (1, \forall E)$$  Just right-click on my mathjax, click on "Show Math As" then click on "TeX commands" to see how I formatted each of these options.  (Also, as I referenced step 1, It would help for you to number each row of your proof.) Else we can't really see your justifications and reference lines.  Just as people can solve an equation and come up with the right answer, but faulty method or reasoning, this is how one proves their work.

Comment: But, again, I applaud the effort you put in, and the care you take in citing the source of your problem.

Comment: Nice!  Very well done. Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions !

Comment: Oops ignore my deleted thinko ...yes, this proof is about as good as it gets, if you don't have disjunctive syllogism built in so you can avoid lines 5 to 9.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @PeterSmith. Using disjunctive syllogism shortens the proof. In this exercise, only basic rules are allowed. But I will keep it in mind as it is useful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

$\def\context#1#2{[#1]\\\left\lvert{#2}\right.}$
Your proof is valid, but you do not *need* to assume $\neg A$.

The contradiction you need for your disjunction elimination can be of the assumption $\neg(A\vee\forall x~B(x))$

That will streamline things a little bit.

$$\fitch{~~1.~\forall x~(A\vee B(x))}{\fitch{~~2.~\neg (A\vee\forall x~B(x))}{\hspace{-1ex}\left\lvert \raise{11ex}{{~~3.~A\vee B(c)\hspace{10ex}\forall\mathsf E~1\\\fitch{~~4.~A\hspace{13ex}\textsf{Assume}}{~~5.~A\vee\forall x~B(x)\hspace{2ex}\vee\mathsf I~4\\~~6.~\bot\hspace{13ex}\neg\mathsf E~2,5\\~~7.~B(c)\hspace{11ex}\mathsf X~6}\\\fitch{~~8.~B(c)\hspace{11ex}\textsf{Assume}}{}\\~~9.~B(c)\hspace{14ex}\vee\mathsf E~3,4{-}7,8{-}8}}\right.\\10.~\forall x~B(x)\hspace{12ex}\forall\mathsf I~3{-}9\\11.~A\vee\forall x~B(x)\hspace{7ex}\vee\mathsf I~10\\12.~\bot\hspace{18ex}\neg\mathsf E~2,11}\\13.~\neg\neg (A\vee\forall x~B(x))\hspace{6ex}\neg\mathsf I~2{-}12\\14.~A\vee\forall x~B(x)\hspace{11ex}\neg\neg\mathsf E~13}$$

Answer (score 0):

You might try to prove the contrapositive along these lines (using a form of natural deduction that does not assume a non-empty universe):

[image]